Customize WooCommerce Storefront mini-cart header text based on cart items
I try to customize WooCommerce Storefront mini-cart header, so  there are:

when there are no products in cart, it gives result A text;
when there are 1 product in cart, it gives result B text,
when there are 2 product in cart, it gives result C text,
and so on...

Example 1:

Example 2:

I have googled and found solution only for 0, 1 and 2 products, but this is not it. "artikkel" is "item" translated to my language.
Current "solution" removes header, when 0 items in cart; when one item, translates to 1 item text; and when 2 or more itemS, it translates to other text.
But I need also to have special text for zero, 1, 2, 3-10+ items in cart.
add_filter('gettext', 'translate_reply');
add_filter('ngettext', 'translate_reply');

function translate_reply($translated)
{
$translated = str_ireplace('artikkel', 'nope ostukorvis. Üks loeb, üheksa kuulevad.', $translated);
$translated = str_ireplace('artiklit', 'nopet osukorvis. Õige sõber kaalub enam kui kuld.', $translated);
return $translated;

}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'remove_empty_cart_from_menu' );
function remove_empty_cart_from_menu() {
    if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() == 0 ) {
        remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_header_cart', 60 );
    }
}

When I got to this point with testings, I 50% give up, decided to ask here, can you help me.
This code below is not working, site sort of crashes (some functions start to give error), cart is not working, and the counter goes buggy, but logic is something I need ... Example:
add_filter('ngettext', 'translate_reply');

function translate_reply($translated) {
    if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() == 0 ) {
        $translated = str_ireplace('artiklit', 'nopet osukorvis. Zero.', $translated);
        $translated = str_ireplace('artikkel', 'nope ostukorvis. One.', $translated);
    } else if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() == 1 ) {  
        $translated = str_ireplace('artikkel', 'nope ostukorvis. One.', $translated);
        $translated = str_ireplace('artiklit', 'nopet osukorvis. Two and more or zero.', $translated);
    } else if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() == 2 ) {
        $translated = str_ireplace('artiklit', 'nopet osukorvis. Two.', $translated);
        $translated = str_ireplace('artikkel', 'nope ostukorvis. One.', $translated);
    } else if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() > 2 ) {
        $translated = str_ireplace('artiklit', 'nopet osukorvis. Two and more for testing.', $translated);
        $translated = str_ireplace('artikkel', 'nope ostukorvis. One.', $translated);
    }
    return $translated;
}

Thanks in advance!

Why people leave minuses? I have question, too hard to answer and then they just leave minus?

It's recommended to modify the function responsible for displaying these messages directly. This function is storefront_cart_link(). However, you cannot use remove_action for this, as it's called from another Storefront function.
To safely override it, you can redeclare the function in your child theme's functions.php file. Storefront checks for the existence of this function before using it, so you won't get any errors.
/**
 * Customizes the Storefront cart link text based on item count.
 */
function storefront_cart_link() {
    // Ensure WooCommerce is available.
    if ( ! storefront_woo_cart_available() ) {
        return;
    }

    // Get cart item count.
    $cart_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();

    // Determine text based on cart count.
    if ( 0 === $cart_count ) {
        $text = __( 'nopet osukorvis. Zero.', 'storefront' );
    } elseif ( 1 === $cart_count ) {
        $text = __( 'nope ostukorvis. One.', 'storefront' );
    } elseif ( 2 === $cart_count ) {
        $text = __( 'nope ostukorvis. Two.', 'storefront' );
    } else { // More than 2 items.
        $text = __( 'nope ostukorvis. More than 2.', 'storefront' );
    }

    ?>
    <a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'View your shopping cart', 'storefront' ); ?>">
        <?php echo wp_kses_post( WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal() ); ?>
        <span class="count"><?php echo esc_html( $text ); ?></span>
    </a>
    <?php
}

In my test install it works!
Note: Remember to add or remove a product to see the updated cart. Simply reloading or refreshing the page won't work.

Thanks Moser and Tyler! It's alive! I use Storefront-Deli theme, so I changed 'storefront' parts to 'deli'. And modified the empty Deli functions.php. This is good lesson, can learn from it.
re: "Note: Remember to add or remove a product to see the updated cart. Simply reloading or refreshing the page won't work."
--- yes, when I tested "my" logics I posted here above, then refreshing didn't update the modification, neither adding to cart - then just had to open site in new tab again, and then new codes started to work.
Thanks!
